# Passing credential to DSC from arm template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to pass a user credential to my DSC script via arm template.Its seem template is not passing credential correctly to the dsc.

[DSC and MOF](https://paste.ee/p/ZVLlU)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's whats working for me. Powershell:

```
Param(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
    xxx
)

xxx
```

Arm template:

```
"properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.20",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
        "configuration": {
            "url": "https://url.zip",
            "script": "file.ps1",
            "function": "configuration"
        },
        "configurationArguments": {
            "param": "something"
        }
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
        "configurationArguments": {
            "adminCreds": {
                "userName": "actualusername",
                "password": "actualpassword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not following "adminCreds": {
                "userName": "username",
                "password": "password"
            }
is  username= the actual username or always hardcoed to "username"?

Comment: actual username: "username": "actualUsername"

Comment: haa.. that means i have to store the password as plain text or can i pass it as a parameter?

Comment: also, who can I stop it getting saved as plain text when it is downloaded

Comment: you can pass it, or get it from kv, either way works. not sure I understand the second question

Comment: I am confused.. If the username  and pwd is passed as parameters then why i need [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds

Comment: because script has to accept the passed in credential?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188366/discussion-between-user1716729-and-4c74356b41).